# $X_1,X_2$ iid standard normal with polar coordinates r and p. Are r and p independent?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution, polar-coordinates

I have two scalar random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ and they are both independent and both have standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$. I am letting $r$ and $p$ be the polar coordinates of the point $(X_1,X_2)$, so this means that $X_1=rcos(p)$ and $X_2=rsin(p)$. I am trying to decide if the random variables $r$ and $p$ are independent. I think that they are not but I could be wrong, anyone see why they are or are not?

Comment: Yes (as in the answer by @carmichael561). This is the basis of a method of simulating independent standard normal $X_1$ and $X_2$. The distance from the origin and the angle can be easily simulated (in terms of independent uniform random variables), so transform to rectangular coordinates and you have independent standard normals. Look at 'Box-Muller' transformation if you are interested in this application.

Answer (score 3):

Since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, their joint pdf is
$$ f(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2}{2}} $$

Next, we have $R=\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}$ and $\Theta=\arctan(\frac{Y}{X})$. One can show that the Jacobian of this transformation is $\frac{1}{R}$, hence the joint pdf of $R$ and $\Theta$ is
$$ f(r,\theta)=\frac{r}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}} $$
for $r\geq0$ and $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$. This is the product of the pdfs of $R$ and $\Theta$, so $R$ and $\Theta$ are independent.

Comment: NB $a \equiv r^2/2$ is exponentially distributed, $p(a) = e^{-a}$. This may be an efficient way to simulate samples for $r$.

Comment: Actually, this seems slightly wrong as it overlooks the fact that $\theta = \text{atan2}(X , Y)$. By using arctan, we only see the principle solutions and have $-\pi/2 \le \theta \le \pi/2$