# Converting a probability function from Polar coordinates to Cartesian coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates

I am confused about converting a **Probability Density Function** from **Polar coordinates** to **Cartesian coordinates**.

Here is an example:

In Polar coordinates, we can have a **Gaussian probability function**:

**$P(r,\theta)=Ae^{-r^2/2\sigma^2}$** according to the transformation:
                                 $r^2=x^2+y^2 \textrm{ and }
                             \theta=\tan^{-1}(y/x)$.

This function in Cartesian coordinates should also be a Gaussian function:

**$P(x,y)=Ae^{-(x^2+y^2)/2\sigma^2}$**

**But** somebody told me that in this transformation, I should multiply by the absolute value of the Jacobian determinate in order to have:

**$P(x,y)=Ae^{-(x^2+y^2)/2\sigma^2}/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$**

And the result is not Gaussian anymore!

Could someone tell me which one is correct and also the reason, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

If your function in polar coordinates is a circularly symmetric Gaussian centered at the origin,
 then it could be written
$P_{r\, \theta}(r,\theta)=A\,r\,e^{-r^2/2\sigma^2}$ and you can obtain $A$ from

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\infty P_{r\, \theta}(r,\theta) \,dr\, d\theta = 1.$$

Integration yields:  $\displaystyle A = \frac{1}{2 \pi  \sigma^2}$.

The Jacobian of the transformation is $$J(x,y)=\begin{vmatrix}\cos \theta& -r \sin \theta \\  \sin \theta &r\cos \theta \end{vmatrix}={r}. $$ so that (see text referenced in the comments below)

$$P_{x\, y}(x,y)= \frac{P_{r,\,\theta}(r,\theta)}{|J(x,y)|}=\frac{1}{r}P_{r,\, \theta}\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x}\right).$$

Thus
$$\displaystyle P_{x\, y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi \sigma^2} e^\frac{-(x^2 + y^2)}{2\sigma^2}.$$

Comment: Thank you. But why the integration of $P(r,\theta)$ cannot be $\int^{2\pi}_0 \int^\infty_{-\infty} P(r,\theta)drd\theta$?

Comment: If you had a piece of graph paper in Cartesian coordinates, each square would have equal area.  Now produce a "polar piece of graph paper":  Draw concentric circles at radii 1,2,3, ...  Now starting at origin, draw uniformly spaced rays, say spaced at 10 degrees, for example.  The sectors closer to the origin are smaller in area, the sectors near circles with larger radii are larger.  The scaling factor is exactly "r" and this is the "multiplication factor" needed to integrate a function over some region of space, or all space.

Comment: if you look at the answer in this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1932170/x-1-x-2-iid-standard-normal-with-polar-coordinates-r-and-p-are-r-and-p-indepe. They added the Jacobin term in the converting process.

Comment: You are right!  That is the convention (at least in the textbook I just looked in!).

Comment: In a calculus class, we would (usually) apply the Jacobian to the differential.  Seems that the probability convention (Papoulis), is to transform the probability density function itself.

Comment: Could you tell me your text book name please? I would like to know how it is strictly proved.

Comment: A.  Papoulis **Probability, random variables, and stochastic processes  4th ed.**  It is not proved.  That is the adapted convention.  But please, have a look at the book.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to look at it

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect what we've learned and discussed in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your transformation takes a PDF in $r$ and converts it into a Joint Density Function in ${x,y}$. So what you really need to do is preserve the normalising property i.e.,

$$\int_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty} \int_{y=-\infty}^{y=\infty} P(x,y)dxdy =1$$

See if you can take it from here.

Comment: For integrate the $P(r,\theta)$, I should use $rdrd\theta$ or $drd\theta$?

Comment: Your PDF is axi-symmetric and so independent of $\theta$. You'd have to work out the double integral in $x$ and $y$, not $r$. The parameter $A$ is presumably defined such that the PDF in $r$ is properly normalised.

Comment: You would also need to express $\sigma$ which is really $\sigma_r$ (the standard deviation of the radial location) in terms of $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ from the transformation rule.