# Joint PDF transform using jacobian

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Seriously I dont have any idea what is this thing called. I know how to find Joint PDf of two variables.. But i dont know how to transform it in other variables ?

Do they require Jacobians?

Here is my doubt regarding this question: how to solve it?
[image]

If you tell me what is this topic called it will be very helpful i would like to see it first... but if you solve it also I will be highly obliged:)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1932170/x-1-x-2-iid-standard-normal-with-polar-coordinates-r-and-p-are-r-and-p-indepe might give you some ideas.

Comment: thanks for comment .. this works for.. independent case .. what about first case ... in which it is not given that whether these are independent or not .. we consider them as dependent i guess ? @StubbornAtom

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the change of basis formula of PDFs:
$$g_{Z,\Theta} (z,\theta) = \vert J \vert p_{X,Y}(f(z,\theta),g(z,\theta))$$
where $X = f(z,\theta)$ and $Y = g(z,\theta)$.
With a bit of math, you can show that 
$$X = f(z,\theta)=\sqrt{z} \cos \theta$$
and
$$Y = g(z,\theta) = \sqrt{z} \sin \theta$$
and the determinant of the Jacobian is

$$\vert J \vert = \det \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f(z,\theta)}{\partial z} &\frac{\partial f(z,\theta)}{\partial \theta} \\ \frac{\partial g(z,\theta)}{\partial z} &\frac{\partial g(z,\theta)}{\partial \theta} \end{bmatrix} = \det \begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{z}}\cos \theta& -\sqrt{z}\sin\theta\\ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{z}}\sin \theta& \sqrt{z}\cos \theta
\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{2}$$
So
$$g_{Z,\Theta} (z,\theta) = \frac{1}{2} p_{X,Y}(\sqrt{z} \cos \theta,\sqrt{z} \sin \theta) \tag{1}$$
The [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1932170/x-1-x-2-iid-standard-normal-with-polar-coordinates-r-and-p-are-r-and-p-indepe) that @StubbornAtom shared works out the PDF for the normal case but for $Z = \sqrt{X^2 + y^2}$. Here we do $Z = X^2 + Y^2$, the PDF of a standard normal is 
$$p_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}$$
Replacing the above in equation $(1)$, we get
$$g_{Z,\Theta} (z,\theta) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{(\sqrt{z} \cos \theta)^2+(\sqrt{z} \sin \theta)^2}{2}} = \frac{1}{4\pi}e^{-\frac{z}{2}} $$
independent of $\Theta $!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: yes thank you .. that changes everything @StubbornAtom

Comment: $|J|=\frac12$ or 1 ?

Comment: and in last line ... you meant $g_{Z,\Theta} (z,\theta) =\frac12 p_{X,Y}(\sqrt{z} \cos \theta,\sqrt{z} \sin \theta)$ ? or $g_{Z,\Theta} (z,\theta) =1. p_{X,Y}(z \cos \theta,z \sin \theta)$