# Why is the scatter plot of two uncorrelated random variables in circle shape?

Tags: probability, statistics, covariance, correlation

I am trying to understand why the scatter plot of two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ is in a circle shape when $corr(X,Y)=0$. Is there any intuitive explanation for this?

[image]

Comment: This is true for Normally distributed random variables. Transform to polar coordinates to see why this symmetry exists e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1932170/x-1-x-2-iid-standard-normal-with-polar-coordinates-r-and-p-are-r-and-p-indepe

Comment: Is that image an example from a book? If so, it could be a lot of things. One, just a coincidence. Two, and this usually happens in reality, is that both variables are from something similar to a normal distribution. When taking data from a multivariate normal distribution, you tend to see these circles or ellipses. Take a look at the wikipedia page for an image of this ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution )

Comment: It is not true when the two random variables each have a uniform density over an interval.  But for bivariate normal distributions with zero mean and correlation, the joint density density is a function of the sum of the squares of the individual components, and so a function of the radial distance